# Upstream pulls with the GitHub desktop client

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I can't seem to find an option to perform a 'git pull upstream master' using the Mac desktop client for GitHub (currently 1.2.13). Is that supported yet outside of the command line?

Comment: I've added a new post showing how it is possible in the latest version.

Comment: Currently there is an option to pull from the upstream. Click on Branch -> Merge into current branch this will show upstream/master or upstream/default-branch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Github client does not support this feature as far as I can tell.

The way to work around this you can change the primary repo to the upstream repo that you want to use and then change the repo back to your own.

1. Go to the settings tab
2. Change the "Primary remote repository" to the upstream repo you want to use.
3. Press "Update Remote"
4. Press "Sync Branch"
5. Change the "Primary remote repository" back to the original forked repo you were using.
6. Press "Update Remote"

And you're done.

[image]

Comment: That seems to work, but it's not very user friendly. At this point, I think I'll just keep using the command line.

Comment: @JoostSchuur I totally agree, the command line is the way to go. I've recently had to explain version control to a third party and tried to use the app but ran in to this problem. The app is definitely not for serious use with multiple people working on a project.

Comment: Sadly, makes the otherwise great app not something useful for directing my users to employ.

Comment: FYI: this does not work for the Windows client as the 'Primary remote repository' textfield is read-only.

Comment: Since the Github Desktop release in Fall 2015, this answer is now (happily!) quite out of date.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert Can you edit this answer or link to an appropriate answer to help people?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [mac client's homepage](http://mac.github.com/), the "sync button" will perform this operation for the configured remote repository.

> **Synchronize branches**
>
> The sync button pushes your changes to GitHub and pulls down other’s changes in one operation. It notifies you when you have changes you haven’t pushed or there are new changes on GitHub you haven’t pulled down.

I can't find a way to support multiple remotes with the current version of the client (Version 1.2.13 (b919fb2)), but in a pinch I suppose you could change the "Primary remote repository" under "Settings" on the left sidebar.

Comment: That syncs to the repo you've cloned from, but not if the one you're syncing to was a fork. I want to grab updates made to the original repo that I forked and merge them back in. Via the command line tools, this is done via a repo I've named 'upstream'.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant `<upstream>` as opposed to a remote by that name. I can't find support for multiple repositories in the most recent version, and edited the answer slightly. You might be stuck with the command line to get what you want without reconfiguring preferences.

Comment: This was added in late 2017: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/pull/3199  and the latest Mac client has a button that explicitly says "pull alexch/master" where alexch is the username of the upstream repo

Comment: ...along with a little line diagram showing upstream and local, and a "Create Pull Request" button

Answer (score 1):

With the New Github desktop there is a feature to directly do this via Branch -> "Update from " this will bring all changes locally and then you can push it via clicking sync / push button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with recent versions of the GitHub client (at least the Mac version), but it's not particularly easy.

The process involves syncing the master version down to your computer as a second fork and then making a pull request to yourself. It's convoluted enough that I made a blog post explaining how to do it:

http://prolatio.blogspot.com/2015/08/merge-upstream-into-your-fork-in-github.html

[edit: the newest Beta of the GitHub desktop app, released by 12 Aug. 2015, makes it possible to do so much more easily. This answer will become obsolete soon.]

Comment: but in the 2017+ Desktop the process has changed again and none of the posts now are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do this...

Firstly, launch a terminal window at the repo root

[image: launch a terminal window at the repo root]

Then you can run `git remote -v` to inspect the currently wired up remotes. Here I can see that the source repo is referenced by name `upstream`

[image]

Then you can either do a pull into your current local branch with `git pull <remote> <branchname>`

[image]

Alternatively, to reset your branch index and working tree to the latest commit of the upstream remote, just use `git reset --hard upstream/master`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Desktop fetches all of the `upstream` branches in your fork, so you should see them appear in the branch list as `upstream/<branch>`.

You can select these branches when using the merge branch feature in GitHub Desktop to merge the changes from upstream into your fork.